# Always format String or Number to XX.XX

Tags: swift, number-formatting

I am trying to format any number to XX.XX

I have tried as below

```
import Foundation

let b = 2.1
var str = String(format:"%.02f", b)
print(str) // 2.10
//Needed output as 02.10
```

But I need the output as 02.10

```
If the number is 0.8 then it should be 00.80
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: FYI - `%.02f` is the same thing as `%.2f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are looking for would be `"%05.2f"`, but
you can use a the `NumberFormatter`:

```
import Foundation

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
```

Then:

```
formatter.string(from: 0.8)! // Will be 00.80
formatter.string(from: 2.1)! // Will be 02.10
```

Comment: Thanks Hosseini, you saved my time, it works as expected....!